# Does express route solve the connectivity issues between tibco ems servers and azure virtual machines?

Tags: tibco-ems

I have a requirement where we are moving our Onprem servers to Azure Vms, one of the windows service listens to tibco ems queues. we are planning to use ExpressRoute to solve this.
I want to know does it solve our requirement or do we face any challenges in connecting?

Comment: I see it is voted down, i have posted this question as few might have faced similar kind of challenges and sharing those might save the time for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have two ways to connect to a remote an EMS server :
. Just use the EMS client library and connect to your remote server
. Setup a local EMS server and create TIBCO EMS routes between your local EMS and the remote EMS server

Obviously the first solution is much more simple and cheaper to set-up, meanwhile in case the network link to your remote EMS server will be down your application will no longer be able to send messages (in other words your application will get an error every time it will try to send a message).

The second solution requires more resources and efforts to be set-up but would make network failure transparent for the applications (except for the delay in message transmission).

I think the criterias to choose the solution would be the volume of data to be exchanged, the criticality of your application, the reliability of the network link and the costs.

I assume a link based on Azure Express Route should offer a high level of reliability but may be to be confirmed with Microsoft.